# Как найти только что созданный объект, созданный через Instantiate в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, есть ли какая нибудь возможность обратиться к только что созданному через Instantiate объекту? Или помогите с логикой, я запутался.

Есть сцена, в ней расставлены пустые ГО - это точки спавна. Эти ГО в массиве, из них выбирается рандомный и в нем создается новый ГО. Как можно узнать в какой точке спавна сейчас создался объект? И как запомнить его место для последующего использования?

Comment: метод `Instantiate` возвращает созданный объект. В чём проблема? `var x = Instantiate(...)`

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него.

Comment: А за что здесь минусы?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```cs
<ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ> = Instantiate(...) as GameObject;
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (*)
```

* преобразуем результат из типа `Object` в тип `GameObject`.

И далее и этим объектом уже делаем что надо.

В [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).